# Complex Find and Replace String

Tags: python, text, replace

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
    
data = 'Machine 1 memsize = "3500" sga = "true" vCpu = "2" Machine 2 memsize = "3578" sga = "true" vCpu = "2" Machine 3 memsize = "3612" sga = "true" vCpu = "2" Machine 4 memsize = "3612" sga = "false" vCpu = "5" ... '
```

I have this variable "data". In this variable, I have a lot of Machine and memsize information. How can I make one function that finds the value 'memsize = ' and change the value that stays between "...." For another value. E.g. 3500, 3578,3612,3612 for 4200? I don't how if I make myself clear in the explanation...

The output that I expect will be this:

```
    data = 'Machine 1 memsize = "4200" sga = "true" vCpu = "2" Machine 2 memsize = "4200" sga = "true" vCpu = "2" Machine 3 memsize = "4200" sga = "true" vCpu = "2" Machine 4 memsize = "4200" sga = "false" vCpu = "5" ... '
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no way to do what you are looking for efficiently, but looking at this string there is an alternative solution to what you what, what I say you do is make a class and store the machine and memsize there so something like this:

```
class Machine():
    def __init__(self, machine, memsize):
        machine = self.machine
        memsize = self.memsize
```

, or you could do a dictionary so something like this:

```
machines = {
    "machine": 1,
    "memsize": 4200
}
```

Hope this helps, if you need anything else just ask me and I'll be more than happy to help you.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that I have on text.file that have this type of situation. And I need to replace the values for one other value that put like example 4200...

Comment: Glad it helps. Do you need any help with replacing the values?

Comment: Sorry but you are not making yourself very clear any extra info would get us to the same page.

Comment: I issue here is I'm making one Python script that open 5 VMware virtual machines .vmx files, in this files I will need to replace the size of memory to other value. Each .vmx file have a diffent memory size. So I need to do something smart do replace this values... I use the example of one variable to make the example more simple... But the if have a solution for this problem I adapt to may real life problem.